# How to determine total size of ASP.Net cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, performancecounter

I'm using the ASP.net cache in a web project, and I'm writing a "status" page for it which shows the items in the cache, and as many statistics about the cache as I can find. Is there any way that I can get the total size (in bytes) of the cached data? The size of each item would be even better. I want to display this on a web page, so I don't think I can use a performance counter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am looking at my performance monitor and under the **ASP.NET Apps v2.0.50727** category I have the following cache related counters:

**Cache % Machine Memory Limit Used**

**Cache % Process Memory Limit Used**

There are also a lot of other cache related metrics under this category.

These should be able to get you the percentage, then if you can get the total allowed with `Cache.EffectivePrivateBytesLimit` or some other call you should be able to figure it out. I do not have personal experience with these counters so you will have to do some research and testing to verify.

Here is a quick start article on reading from performance counters:
http://quickstart.developerfusion.co.uk/quickstart/howto/doc/PCRead.aspx

Comment: PerformanceCounter pc = new PerformanceCounter("ASP.NET Applications", "Cache % Machine Memory Limit Used", true);
        pc.InstanceName = "__TOTAL__";
        CacheMachineMemoryLimitUsedLiteral.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}%", pc.NextValue());

Comment: Note, due to Markdown, Mike's code should have two underscores at the start and end of "__TOTAL__"

Comment: markdown in comments are the same that exist in messages, just add the ` before and after the code to be used as "code"... for this example: `pc.InstanceName = "__Total__";` witch can be read from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Have not tried it. But maybe you can use [Cache Manager plug-in for ASP.NET](http://www.aspalliance.com/CacheManager/Default.aspx). Or use it as example.

Comment: This website hurt my eyes :P

Comment: This link is dead and I couldn't find the article on the ASP Alliance site :(