# How to determine the size of an ASP.net Cache Item?

Tags: asp.net, caching

I know that its possible to get the total size of the ASP.net Cache  ([How to determine total size of ASP.Net cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344210/how-to-determine-total-size-of-asp-net-cache))

But is it possible to break down the that total into the individual items stored in cache?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using the asp.net in memory cache or a caching service?  The .net cache uses a pointer whereas a caching service will need to serialize your data and both of these will result in different object sizes.

Comment: I'm using the asp.net cache: HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you just need a one off report then you can serialize each object that is returned and count the bytes.

```
 Dim Stream As New IO.MemoryStream
 Dim FM As New LosFormatter
 FM.Serialize(Stream, Myobject)
 dim O as object = Stream.ToArray
 Trace.Write(O.length) 'The size of the object that you want to measure
```

Comment: FYI, not all objects in the cache are serializable (that's only a requirement for out-of-proc caching).