# ASP.NET how to get Cache in KB used for this application?

Tags: .net, asp.net, caching, performancecounter

I need to know what is Cache size. I've read [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344210/how-to-determine-total-size-of-asp-net-cache) on this site for more or less similar question but it partly serves me. 
As i know i can get values from PerMon, here is function

```
public static string getCacheSize()
{
    PerformanceCounter pc = new PerformanceCounter("ASP.NET Applications", "Cache % Machine Memory Limit Used","__TOTAL__", true); 
    return string.Format("{0:0.00}%", pc.NextValue()); 
}
```

1.it gives me percents when i need KB and there is no item closest to this one in PerfMon
2.it shows 70.5% used while all memory usage is about 50%

any help ?

Comment: this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344210/how-to-determine-total-size-of-asp-net-cache) might help you with an answer.

Comment: this is the partly solution i've mentioned in post, still stuck where it ended in there...