# How to check size of Page.Cache?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, caching

Is there any method to check size of all objects in Page.Cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at this very good article [explore session and cache](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/session/exploresessionandcache.aspx)

and also check this thread [how-to-determine-total-size-of-asp-net-cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344210/how-to-determine-total-size-of-asp-net-cache)